# Google map in my android appilcation does not work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I run my Google map application this error message comes up and the app closes :

> Unfortunately ggmaps has stopped.

I can't figure out what went wrong. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ggmaps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest (updated)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ggmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
    android:name="com.example.ggmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.ggmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4452000" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ggmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCLNoY5xaeZJuYBA3vTI3oua3lrsstUMjk"


             />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ggmaps/com.example.ggmaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.example.ggmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     ... 11 more
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 4452000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4869)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
08-05 10:16:30.425: E/AndroidRuntime(9818):     ... 21 more
08-05 10:16:30.746: E/android.os.Debug(2381): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
08-05 10:16:30.926: E/dalvikvm(2381): The following issues were seen:
08-05 10:16:36.805: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2381): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2125d9c8 that was originally bound here
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2125d9c8 that was originally bound here
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1746)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:158)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:146)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.restoreAccountsIfNeeded(AccountServiceProxy.java:135)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$11.run(ExchangeService.java:4575)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:986)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:983)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-05 10:16:39.576: E/ActivityThread(9959):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-05 10:16:52.196: E/Watchdog(2381): !@Sync 105
08-05 10:17:22.195: E/Watchdog(2381): !@Sync 106
08-05 10:17:52.196: E/Watchdog(2381): !@Sync 107
08-05 10:18:22.196: E/Watchdog(2381): !@Sync 108
```

Comment: When you use new google-play-services jar you have to define this meta data info  <meta-data        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="4452000" /> in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: which exception you are getting..?

Comment: hey is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this meta tag in manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="5077000" />
```

Comment: check now it was version issue

Comment: This is the only answer that actually addresses the error in your logcat:  <Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 4452000.>

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
  <permission
            android:name="com.example.ggmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in your Manifest file .

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines inside the `application` tag

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4452000" />
```

And these permissions outside of `application` tag

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.example.ggmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.ggmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```